# Play framework: Extract common functionality into a shared submodule

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have three Play! 2.3 applications that share a lot of common code, both on the model layer and the view layer. Each application is on its own git repository. What would be a good way to extract all the common parts of the applications into a single module that all three applications will depend on (so that I don't have to change the common code three times - one for each app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new Play project called `commons`
2. Add the common code located in your other projects
3. Publish your `commons` project locally with `activator publish-local`
4. Add the dependency to each project's `build.sbt` like any other dependency

**Note 1** : Don't forget to add `organization := "com.yourcompany"` in `commons`'s `build.sbt` to have a dependency structure like this :

```
"com.yourcompany %% "commons" % "1.0.0"
```

**Note 2** : if you want to deploy your application to a server, you will have to host your `commons` project in an external repository (Maven central, Artifactory, OSS Sonatype...) or publish your applications after having built them locally with `activator dist`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was the direction I was heading as well. I haven't had the chance to test it thoroughly yet, but from first looks it seems that I cannot access the 'commons' views from the parent project yet. It is possible to access model/views/controllers of the 'commons' project from the parent project, right?

Comment: Apparently the js/css of the common project are available under the url path /lib/commons/, so that solves it for me.